# How to boot to Ubuntu desktop from the console

Tags: boot, tty, console

My laptop is installed with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu. I can use both OSs. I've been using Ubuntu for one week. I start up my laptop, and then I go to Ubuntu, but I just see the virtual console screen shown below. Why can't I boot to Ubuntu desktop? I already entered my username and password.

[image]

Comment: What is the result of `runlevel` command?

Answer (score 1):

1. At the screen that says `Ubuntu 15.10 pilay-Inspiron 3442 tty1`, open a text-only virtual console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. Actually the `tty1` in your screenshot indicates that you have already completed this step.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. After you have logged in in the console type:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start graphical.target
   ```

   and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up your default purple login screen and then login to your Ubuntu desktop environment as usual.

#### Why is this happening?

This error could be caused by having installed the wrong graphics driver. Run this command in the terminal to show the available graphics drivers:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Wait at least one minute for the command to scan your computer and generate the list of drivers. The output of this command will be a list of the package names and short descriptions of the available drivers. In addition to showing a list of the available drivers, the above command will often also identify the recommended proprietary driver(s) for your system.

Comment: I do that as you say type "sudo service lightdm start" in terminal. But it is not ok. It reply error to me. Pls check the following photos is problem. How I can solve this problem? Pls help me. Thanks.