# Unable to login after failed update and black screen

Tags: 16.04

I was updating Ubuntu to a newer version and I don't think it completed when my laptop was turned off. Now when I try to use the system it goes to the black login screen, but I don't know my username because it never required it before. How can I login and/or change it back to how it was previously?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to boot to Ubuntu desktop from the console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805536/how-to-boot-to-ubuntu-desktop-from-the-console)

Comment: Close voters crafting answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try user-name: ubuntu
with no password.

Default user:
[Live CD asks for a username and password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103896/live-cd-asks-for-a-username-and-password)

If that doesn't work, try this:
[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

If nothing works reinstall

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A normal installation of Ubuntu will create a directory under `/home` for each user. You can easily locate the users names by booting from live media, mounting the drive that contains your home directory and looking at the names there by opening a terminal and issuing the command `ll /mnt/point/home` where /mnt/point/ is the point you mounted your drive at. this results in output like this:

> drwxr-xr-x 94 me   me          4096 Mar 24 10:57 me/

Where 'me' is your username.

note the the `d` at the beginning of the line signifies that it's a directory and both the user and group listed match the directory name at the end of the line (less the `/`).

Having obtained your username you can now reboot (removing the live media) and login normally with your username and password.

Note: Unless you are storing /home on a separate drive or partition, the above should be sufficient.

If anything about this answer is unclear, drop me a comment and I'll do my best to clarify.