# on interface of ubuntu login

Tags: password

I am installing Ubuntu desktop downloaded just now from here. Only after a few minutes, "ubuntu login:" showed on the screen after pressed Ctrl+Alt+F2. I tried to input admin, then on "Password:", I can't pass it. Could you let me know what account and password I can use here?

Much thank in advance!

George

Comment: Why did you press Ctrl+Alt+F2 when presented with a login prompt? Is there a user on the machine called “admin”, or is it something else? There simply isn’t enough information here to guess about why you cannot use the system as expected.

Comment: It is 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Hi Matigo, thank you for your question.

Comment: @George - welcome to ask Ubuntu. It’s nice to thank matigo for the question, but you’ll need to answer the questions he posed and provide a bit more information if you want anyone to help. I don’t think there’s enough information here to help you, sorry.

Comment: There is no link for "*downloaded from here*." Please edit your question to include the actual download link you used.

Comment: The description of your problem is ambiguous. Have you already installed Ubuntu?  Why are you using CTRL+ALT+F2?  Are you doing this through a live session?  Please edit your question and include more context and details so we can understand the problem

Comment: Hi Matigo, thank you for your question. After booting from usb, I can see there is flashes on top left of screen, I found solution here. It told me to try Ctrl+Alt+Fn. So, I got Ctrl+Alt+F2 let me see the login interface. thanks,

Comment: "download from here" means download from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Were you able to install Ubuntu Desktop onto your computer? Or are you seeing the black screen when you boot from the Installation USB/DVD? Could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of your computer? This will make it easier to offer a more complete suggestion 

Comment: My computer is HP Elitebook 8560P. It has 16G RAM and 250G HD. It booted from usb.  ubunbu was installed on C drive I believe. After installed it only minutes, I saw flashes on top left of the screen which was black, pressed Ctrl+Alt+F2, then got login screen ( no reboot).

Comment: I think I understand now: I think the OP is asking an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The OP has actually [booted to a black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it), and is following random instructions from goodness-knows-where. As part of these instructions, the OP hit CTRL+ALT+F2 to  reach a TTY login, and is now puzzled because the password field does not echo any keypresses (normal behavior).

Comment: i downloaded unbuntu from ubuntu.com/download/desktop and burned it to a usb. I booted my computer which is hp elitebook 8560P, 16G RAM and 250G HD from the usb. After booting it, there were flashes on the top left corner of the screen. i searched it up and it told me to press Ctrl+Alt+F2. so i did and it brought me to a log in page. but i don't know the username or password, there is no sign up page only login. So what is the username and password? shouldn't there be "admin" or "rout" and the password?

Comment: @user535733, yes, you are right. But the solution was found at a forum of ubuntu.com.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to boot to Ubuntu desktop from the console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805536/how-to-boot-to-ubuntu-desktop-from-the-console)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused by two things.

1. Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> will indeed sweep you away from your graphical desktop environment to a different input console (TTY).

   **Simply press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to return to the graphical desktop environment**. Be patient. It might take a minute to re-load. Let it.
2. On the F2 TTY, your password is ignored when you try to type it.

   In fact, the password IS detected by the system. The lack of any echo or feedback on the screen is a decades-old security technique.

   Use exactly the same login name and password that you use on the graphical desktop. There is no "admin" account or special password. YOUR account is the admin account; that's why you have sudo.

   If you **simply enter the correct password blindly, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>**, the system will indeed let you in. However, it will let you in to a shell prompt, not the graphical environment.

Comment: after pressed Ctrl+Alt+F1, screen came back to flashes on the top left corner, even after a few minutes the login page doesnt show up anymore. what can I do?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Following the guide of your link, it came into graphical desktop environment. And there is an Install Ubunbu 20.04.3 LTS icon on the desktop. So, do I need to click it to install the LTS ?

Comment: Following your link, I chosen  "Try Ubuntu without installing.", Then, my computer came into graphical desktop environment. The Install Ubunbu 20.04.3 LTS icon is on the top of task bar and on the desktop. On the desktop there are 3 icons. They are Ubuntu, Trash and Install Ubunbu 20.04.3 LTS icon. So, I question is that I need to click the  Install Ubunbu 20.04.3 LTS icon to install the LTS .

Comment: Hi, I already installed 20.0.4.3 LTS successfully by click the Install Ubunbu 20.04.3 LTS icon on desktop. Thank all of you!